# Chrome disables Javascript non secure page

Tags: google-chrome, security, javascript

i have a few websites that chrome shows as unsecure and wont load its javascript content.
https://www.agl.com.au/get-connected/electricity-gas-plans
https://www.cashrewards.com.au/en/refer-a-friend

by right click/inspect/then looking at the console tab i found

Failed to load resource:net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

with both of those if i opened the link under that header in new window it brings up the "not secure" page and then you have to show advanced and proceed.

then the website will load.

But now i have a local ip address thats showing not secure and wont load the Javascript. it doesn't have the save error as above to fix it so im a little lost.

is there some way i can disable chrome disabling javascript or atleast give me an option of being able to view it